# Threading lifetime error

Tags: concurrency, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to implement the game "Tower of Hanoi" using concurrency in Rust. Honestly, I tried to understand the whole lifetime thing in Rust in the last time, but I'm not done yet. That's why I get some weird lifetime errors which I don't understand. First, here is the important piece of code

```
fn move_plate<'a>(stack_a: &'a mut Vec<i32>, stack_b: &'a mut Vec<i32>, 
    stack_c: &'a mut Vec<i32>, moves: &'a mut Vec<(i32, i32)>) 
{
        let mut moves1: Vec<(i32, i32)> = Vec::new();
        let guard1 = Thread::scoped(
            move || { move_plate(stack_a, stack_c, stack_b, (1, 3, 2), &mut moves1); 
        });
        guard1.join().ok();
}
```

And here is the error

```
error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
    let guard1 = Thread::scoped(move || {
                     move_plate(height - 1, stack_a, stack_c, stack_b, (1, 3, 2), threads, depth + 1, &mut moves1);
                 });
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the expression at 93:25...
             let guard1 = Thread::scoped(move || {

note: ...so that the declared lifetime parameter bounds are satisfied
             let guard1 = Thread::scoped(move || {

note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the expression at 93:45...
             let guard1 = Thread::scoped(move || {
                 move_plate(height - 1, stack_a, stack_c, stack_b, (1, 3, 2), threads, depth + 1, &mut moves1);
             });
note: ...so type `closure[]` of expression is valid during the expression
             let guard1 = Thread::scoped(move || {
                 move_plate(height - 1, stack_a, stack_c, stack_b, (1, 3, 2), threads, depth + 1, &mut moves1);
             });
error: declared lifetime bound not satisfied
             let guard1 = Thread::scoped(move || {
```

I understand that I have to avoid the thread to outlive the function, because otherwise the reference to moves would be gone. But since I join the thread, that should be all right, shouldn't it? What am I missing at that point?
Would be really nice if somebody could help me, I'm just getting used to that cool (but complicated) kind of stuff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the Rust type system. Currently Rust allows to send data between threads only if this data satisfies `Send` bound, and `Send` implies `'static` - that is, the only references which can be sent across thread boundaries are `'static` ones.

There is [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/458) which partially lifts this limitation, allowing non-`'static` references to be sent across tasks. I thought that it already has been accepted, but it is not (which is strange). The API that supports such thing has already been created (and this is likely why you are confused), but the language is yet to be adjusted.